# HTML5 Video as Background leaving HTML artifacts on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, video, css, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video running as a background image with a z-index of -1000. I have some html elements on top of said video that z-index:0. Whenever the window is resized, HTML artifacts are left behind that do not go away until page refresh. Seems to be an issue with the render layer but I cannot figure it out. Suggestions?

Here is a picture of what's happening:

[image]

The gray pieces should not be there.

Edit: Only tested on webkit so far.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the HTML5 video element to the end of the body and it fixed the issue oddly enough.